# What are tags useful for?

Tags: discussion, tags

Note: The original question here was meant to be
an information-gathering survey
but was clearly misunderstood and has been changed
to match a useful answer to a different question.

**What are tags useful for?**

Answer (score 6):

#### I apply tags to warn solvers who would just waste their time looking at my puzzle

This can be liberating as it eases guilt
when a puzzle targets a small audience.

Answer (score 5):

Straight from the [tags page itself](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags):

> A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question.

Basically, tags are a **categorisation system**. What are they useful for?

- **To describe *what kind of question* is being asked.** If you see a puzzle tagged [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle), you know it's going to have a riddle element to it; if you see a puzzle tagged [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher), you know it's going to have a cipher element. That way you get an idea of the approximate nature of the puzzle without having to read the whole thing.
- **To help increase searchability.** If you want to find a particular riddle, then you don't want a bunch of cipher puzzles cluttering up your search results, so you add `[riddle]` to the search terms. See also [How do I search for questions with (or without) specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-or-without-specific-tags) on main meta.
- **To act as a 'bat signal' for experts.** If I see a question tagged [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle) or [mathematics](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics), I'm going to have a look at it and see whether I can apply my knowledge of riddling or maths to solve it. This is also where the concept of **favourite tags** comes in: an expert in geometry, say, can favourite the [geometry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) tag so that they get the puzzles they're most interested in - and most likely to be able to answer - highlighted for them.
- **To warn people off the things they're *not* interested in.** Conversely, if I see a question tagged [computer-puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-puzzle), I'm very unlikely to be able to solve it. I may give it a cursory glance, but there are so many others on this site much better suited to solving such puzzles than I. Personally I don't ignore tags, but this is where the concept of **ignored tags** comes in: someone who hates riddles, say, can put the [riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle) tag on ignore so that they don't have to be bothered by such puzzles.

For more information, see [Why do we tag questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/why-do-we-tag-questions) and [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions) on main meta. Of course none of that is Puzzling-specific, but a surprising amount of it does apply to Puzzling as well as to more conventional Q&A sites.

To find out how *individual* tags are used, we have the **tag wikis**, which should ideally include usage guidance for the tag and tell you exactly what kind of questions are supposed to have that tag. These are editable by anyone (subject to community approval for those of you with less than 20k rep), so we can all take part in shaping and improving them to provide the best possible guidance for each tag.

Comment: The point of this question is to break it down and find out what actually happens.

Comment: @humn I don't really understand what the issue is here. Tags are a categorisation system - what other way is there of using them?

Comment: Let's find out.

Comment: I don't think @humn is asking "What are tags for," or even, "How should tags be used," but rather, "In what ways do you, personally, use tags on Puzzling.SE?".  This is meant to be a survey, to determine for what purpose tags are most used *in practice* on this site.  So if you can break your bullet points into separate answers, we can see who *actually* uses tags for those purposes.

Comment: Tags shouldn't be used for anything other than what the tag system is designed for. If they are, they _need_ to stop. This is a point that makes this survey... kinda moot. It means there actually _is_ a correct answer to this question, and this is it.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain What Emrakul said :-) Essentially, humn is asking the wrong question: tags are intended for a particular purpose, so we should be looking at what that purpose is (and perhaps how some people can improve their tagging practices based on that) rather than polling people on how they (perhaps inappropriately) use tags.

Comment: @Emrakul, one of my favorite aspects of this site is how it encourages flexible thinking. Many members probably do apply tags just as instructed but many obviously don't and this question addresses the other side as well: using tags when searching and filtering.

Comment: @Emrakul I don't think there is a correct answer to "How *do* you use tags," although I would tend to agree that there is a correct answer to "How *should* you use tags."  Whether the question as asked is worth asking, or belongs on meta at all, is something else to discuss, but the question *as asked* doesn't have one correct answer.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Fair enough, I'll go with that.

Comment: @humn I've spent a while today wondering what to reply to your last comment, but I see you've now gone ahead and done it :-)

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort, @randal'thor, misdirected voting kept occurring and this question was just becoming a mess. I'll look into how surveys are really done around here before trying again.

Answer (score 3):

#### I use $\small\boxed{\kern1mu \textsf{Ignored Tags}\,}$ to distinguish, but not actually ignore, popular tags

This creates a three-way system:

1. Highlight for Favorites
2. Lowlight for the vast majority of puzzles
3. Normal for puzzles I would miss otherwise